# Why does Paypal send TWO verification payments not just ONE?

Tags: financial

The process would be easier if there was only one payment, but there must be some security or financial reason for Paypal to send you two random payments

Answer (score 5):

I suspect a 1 in 99 chance of guessing the deposit amount on a fake account using a stolen card, the odds were just too high.

There's 9801 (99 x 99) possible outcomes that anyone trying to guess the deposits would have to pick from - vs the 99 outcomes from one payment.

In order to achieve the same number of outcomes from one payment they would have to deposit anything between 0.01 and 98.01 which would be very generous of them.

But not a UX question really.

Comment: I'd be happy if a vendor deposited $98.01 into my account purely for verification ;)

Comment: Actually only 4900 possibilities... they could be entered in either order. But still far better than 99.

Comment: @MyrddinEmrys: who says they need to be different?

Comment: @MarjanVenema They don't, but that doesn't change the fact that there are 4900 possibilities, not 9801. :-)

Comment: @MyrddinEmrys: ok help me out then. Why only half? First payment has 99 possible amounts, so does the second. That boils down to 9801 possible combinations. The only way to half that number would be a constraint that the total does not exceed a dollar? But that is mentioned anywhere, so what do I miss?

Comment: Lets say the deposits can be 1 or 2. What I think Merlin is saying is that the deposits can be 1&1 1&2 2&1 2&2, but when you enter them at paypal, the order is irrelevant, so in the event of receiving two different payments PayPal would accept 2&1 and 1&2 as both being correct, so despite being 4 combinations, there's 3 unique answers (because 2 overlap). Extrapolate to deposits between 1 and 99, we get 1&2 and 2&1 overlapping, 1&3 and 3&1, 2&3 and 3&2, 1&4 and 4&1, 2&4 and 4&2, 3&4 and 4&3. So while there's 9801 combinations, Paypal is forgiving on 98+97+..+1 of them...

Comment: ... so the real total is 9801-98-97-...-1 =  9801 - (1+98)*98/2 = 9801-4851 = 4950

Comment: Ahh thank you, I was a bit off. :-) I thought my math was wrong, but I couldn't remembe3r the correct formula.